# For string I can use ToString. What to use for decimal?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

```
String ItemName=txtItemName.Text.ToString();
String ItemSpecification=txtItemSpecification.Text.ToString ();
String Category=cmbCategory.SelectedIndex .ToString();
String UnitOfMeasurement=cmbUnitOfMeasurement .SelectedIndex .ToString ();
Decimal Reorderlevel = txtReorderLevel.Text.();
Decimal LifeOfSpan=0;

String NeedApproval=rblNeedApprovalOrNotdx.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
String Description=MemoDescription.Text.ToString ();
```

For `string` I can get a value using `ToString`. How can I get it for `decimal`?

Comment: Syntax error in question itself, it should be Decimal Reorderlevel = txtReorderLevel.Text(); instead of Decimal Reorderlevel = txtReorderLevel.Text.();

Answer (score 0):

Use [Convert.ToDecimal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to convert string to decimal.

The below code prints the value as 1200.00.

```
var convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal("1200.00");
```

Just in case it's cultural issues, try this version which shouldn't depend on your locale at all:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse("1200.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

I have always preferred using the [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods because it is going to spit back success or failure to convert without having to worry about exceptions.

```
string value;
double number;

value = Double.MinValue.ToString();
if (Double.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.", 
                     value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Decimal.TryParse()`, like this:

```
decimal Reorderlevel;
if (Decimal.TryParse(UnitOfMeasurement, out Reorderlevel))
{
    // Conversion from string to decimal succeeded

}
else
{
    // Conversion failed

}
```

---

> Note: `TryParse()` does not thrown an exception if the attempted cast from `string` to `decimal` fails, but rather returns `false` when it fails and `true` when it succeeds.

---

UPDATE:

If you prefer to use a nullable decimal, then do this:

```
decimal tempValue;
decimal? Reorderlevel = Decimal.TryParse(UnitOfMeasurement, out tmpvalue) ?
              tmpvalue : (decimal?)null;
```

Then you can check if `Reorderlevel` has a value before using it, like this:

```
if(Reorderlevel.HasValue)
{
    // Do something with reorder level value here

}
```

Comment: first understand what i need for string we can use as ToString(),like wise for Decimal how to get this?                                                                   String UnitOfMeasurement=cmbUnitOfMeasurement .SelectedIndex .ToString ();
           Decimal Reorderlevel = txtReorderLevel.Text.();

Comment: @user3036427 - updated answer to use the `Reorderlevel` variable and `UnitOfMeasurement` string value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToDecimal() or Decimal.TryParse()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`Convert.ToDecimal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the System namespace.